# Smooth transition between textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image: meadow]

How can I create the trail and grass, with a **smooth** transition of dirt using textures?

Assume I already have the textures and normal maps for trail path, grass and dirt.

I would assume I can use height as a `factor` for choosing between trail path, grass and dirt texture. But this makes the transition too rough/hard and too even.

Image taken from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44880/multiple-texture-displacements-mapping-in-one-scene).

I am using blender 2.82 with Cycles engine.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/166207/

Comment: @JachymMichal That is very close to what I want to do. The linked answer has even distance between the 2 texture blends but I want uneven distance blend